# Adding image right below listview

Tags: android, listview

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"  
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:background="@color/transparentBlack" 
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/gHeader"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/homeCategoryTitleColor"/>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:divider="@color/categorylist_divider" 
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gHeader" 
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@color/transparentBlack" 
        android_layout_below="@+id/android:list"
        android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I have so far. Data in the listview adds dynamically, and for some reason, imageview is always at the bottom of the screen, unless listview fills everything up, which shows fine. Any ideas on how to fix this? I have tried multiple ways, wrapping Layouts to combine other layout to work around, but can't get the ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `android_layout_below` only works on RelativeLayout, and do use `@+id` unless you are **adding** an id. Only use `@id` when referencing one.

Comment: @Taeyoung Lee not getting what u want? Refer here it might help you :- http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-linearlayout/

Comment: @jagjitsingh I am trying to add image footer right below listview. I have implemented imageview right over listview, but can't seem to figure out how to add just below to it. There's a space that I think its coming from the height I set on the listview. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'

library to successfully achieve this. You can specify the percentage same as in HTML.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:clickable="false" 
    android:divider="@color/categorylist_divider" 
    android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gHeader" 
    android:scrollbarSize="10dp" 
    app:layout_hightPercent="70%"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_hightPercent="30%"
    android:background="@color/transparentBlack" 
    android_layout_below="@id/android:list"
    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Pretty cool, I'll give it a try if no other solutions come up to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android_layout_below` use `layout_weight` in your `ListView`.
This is how should looks:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"  
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:background="@color/transparentBlack" 
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/gHeader"
        android:textSize="22dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/homeCategoryTitleColor"/>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   
        android:layout_weight="1"     
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:divider="@color/categorylist_divider" 
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gHeader" 
        android:scrollbarSize="10dp" 
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/transparentBlack" 
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. This was one of the tries I've made, and looked great on portrait mode, but not on Landscape mode. In landscape, it doesn't show the image, just the list. Any idea on how to fix that? Or do you know how to change the weight of layout, like listview/imageview programmatically?

Comment: Woah, I meant to say it to you, not the person above, but this code works amazing.

Comment: Yeap, sadly is not marked as the right answer ;)...well both are correct, but mine works for since I remember :)